# Nodejs page is not rendering

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm making this simple website using Express (Nodejs) and I don't know what's wrong with the web application. It is not rendering contact page in views. I'm using EJS as a view engine. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. It is showing error 500 on Browser, unable to find anything in response and I don't know why it is showing that because everything seems perfect and files are inside accordingly their appropriate folders.

> This is a app.js file (Default file)

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var about = require('./routes/about');
var contact = require('./routes/contact');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/about', about);
app.use('/contact', contact);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

> This is my contact.js file inside default folder routes.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('contact', { title: 'contact' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

> This is contact.ejs file inside views folder.

```
<% incude layout.ejs %>

  <div class="Jombotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h1>About us</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu consequat neque. Quisque aliquam turpis id metus facilisis dapibus. Nullam a tellus dui.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu consequat neque. Quisque aliquam turpis id metus facilisis dapibus. Nullam a tellus dui.
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<% include footer.ejs %>
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: it says `incude layout.ejs` is it a typo?

Comment: is it a layout which I need in all the pages, includes header and footer

Comment: @RolandStarke, It is error 500 on browser. Unable to find anything in response. and I don't know why it is showing that.

Comment: Can you share the actual error screen shot ?  Also try layout('layout') instead of include statement.